# Registering additional validators on PloneFormGen

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

I'm trying to register a new validator to the available list of validators you can select in a PloneFormGen field.

The task seems simple at the beginning: I registered a new Archetypes validator and I found a way to add it to the dropdown list (through a monkey-patch to add new item to `stringValidators` tuple) and a call to `initStringValidators` method of the PFG tool.

Still, selecting my new validator will not lead to anything: the `__call__` method is never called.

What I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tested your validator in a simple archetypes schema/content-type? Make sure it works there before trying to use it in PFG.

Comment: By the way, it might be easier to use formgen_tool.stringValidatorsDL.add( id, title, msgid=i18nid ) rather than monkey patching.
(Using PFG is a little like an archaeology project, isn't it? Exploring those old corners of Plone.)